# Javascript function is undefined after running webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",//path relative to this file
    output: {
        filename: "../frontEnd/bundle.js",//path relative to this file
    },
    externals: {
        puppeteer: 'require("puppeteer")',
    },
    mode: 'development'
  }
```

Here is the file, index.js, where the webpack is ran:

```
var backendScript = require('../backEnd/backend');
var safeBackendScript = require('../backEnd/safeBackend');

function test(){
    document.getElementById("Fname").value= "John"
    document.getElementById("Lname").value= "Smith"
    document.getElementById("Phone").value= "1234567890"
    document.getElementById("Email").value= "Jsmith@domain.com"
    document.getElementById("Saddress").value= "123 Main Street"
    document.getElementById("Zip").value= "12345"
    document.getElementById("country").value= "USA"
    document.getElementById("state").value= "NJ"
    document.getElementById("cardtype").value= "AE"
    document.getElementById("Cname").value= "JOHN H SMTIH"
    document.getElementById("Cnumber").value= "1234567890101112"
    document.getElementById("CVV").value= "123"
    document.getElementById("cardmonth").value= "01"
    document.getElementById("cardyear").value= "2035"
    document.getElementById("category").value= "jackets"
    document.getElementById("kword").value= "Supreme Jacket"
    document.getElementById("delay").value= "120"
    document.getElementById("color").value= "C2"
    document.getElementById("size").value= "L"
}

module.exports = {
    test: test
}
```

And then here is my html with the function ran:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Supreme Bot</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 20px">
   <button onclick="test()"> test </button>
</body>
</html>
```

then after clicking on the button, it states that test() is undefined...
I can't figure it out...
Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't exporting `test()` to `window`.

`module.exports = {...}` won't automagically get injected into `window`, but:

- you can set the `output.libraryTarget: 'window'` and `output.library: 'something'` configuration options and get `window.something.test()` ([docs here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget)), *or*
- you can manually do `window.test = test;` at the end of your Webpack entry point instead of exporting things.